# Trying to find the total number of, distinct, clients logged on weekdays, weekends and both weekday+weekend

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table structure is as follows:

```
node_id | client_id | timestamp
--------+-----------+-----------
    1   |    102    | 2012-02-01 (weekday)
--------+-----------+-----------
    2   |    104    | 2012-02-01 (weekday)
--------+-----------+-----------
    2   |    106    | 2012-02-02 (weekday)
--------+-----------+-----------
    1   |    106    | 2012-02-02 (weekend)
--------+-----------+-----------

(added fake weekday/weekend to simplify things)
```

I need to find the total number of, distinct, client_id's logged on:

- A weekday
- The weekend
- Both a weekday and the weekend

Is it possible to do this in MSSQL? Or will I have to resort to simply dumping all the data and parsing it in my program?

**EDIT:**

From the above table, the desired output would tell me that:

```
3 people were logged on Mon-Fri by nodes 1 & 2
1 person was logged on Sat-Sun by nodes 1
1 person was logged on Mon-Sun by nodes 1 & 2
```

Basically, I need to know how many clients were logged on Mon-Fri, Sat-Sun, Mon-Sun and by which nodes.

Comment: I think we would be better able to help if your example data both matched the real world (Feb 1 and 2 are both weekdays in 2012) and was internally self-consistent (you have Feb 2 as both weekday and weekend as I write).

Answer (score 0):

You can use datepart(weekday,?) to find the day-of-the-week for a date (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx); then its just a matter of specifying which of those you're interested in grouping together.

Comment: Am I on the right track with this? `SELECT node_id, COUNT(DISTINCT node_id), DATEPART(weekday, timestamp) FROM log WHERE DATEPART(weekday, timestamp) NOT IN (6, 7) GROUP BY node_id, DATEPART(weekday, timestamp)` Then I can just edit that `NOT IN` clause to pull the weekday log data and the weekend+weekday log data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can try this

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
declare @tbl table (node_id int identity(1,1), client_id int, dtm datetime)

insert into @tbl (client_id,dtm) values (1,'20111001'), (1,'20111001'),(1,'20111002'),(1,'20111003'),(1,'20111004')
,(2,'20111001'), (2,'20111003'),(2,'20111003'),(2,'20111003'),(2,'20111004')
--weekday
select client_id, COUNT(*)
FROM @tbl
WHERE DATEPART(DW,dtm)<6
GROUP BY client_id
--weekend
select client_id, COUNT(*)
FROM @tbl
WHERE DATEPART(DW,dtm)>5
GROUP BY client_id
```

This solution uses [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function.
To set the first day of the week use [SET DATEFIRST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx).

**EDITED**
In SQL-Server 2005+ you can do it this way:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
DECLARE @tbl table (node_id int, client_id int, dtm datetime)

INSERT INTO @tbl (node_id,client_id,dtm) VALUES (1,102,'20120201'),(2,104,'20120201'),(2,106,'20120202'),(1,106,'20120204')

--weekday
SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) as varchar)+' people were logged on Mon-Fri by nodes '+
    (select cast(node_id as varchar)+',' as 'data()' from @tbl WHERE DATEPART(DW,dtm)<6 GROUP BY node_id for xml path(''))
FROM @tbl
WHERE DATEPART(DW,dtm)<6

--weekend
SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) as varchar)+' people were logged on Sat-Sun by nodes '+
    (select cast(node_id as varchar)+',' as 'data()' from @tbl WHERE DATEPART(DW,dtm)>5 GROUP BY node_id for xml path(''))
FROM @tbl
WHERE DATEPART(DW,dtm)>5

--all week
SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) as varchar)+' people were logged on Mon-Sun by nodes '+
    (select cast(node_id as varchar)+',' as 'data()' from @tbl GROUP BY node_id for xml path(''))
FROM @tbl
```

Comment: How can I find the number of times the nodes logged each client_id on both a weekday and the weekend?

Comment: @Kane Didn't get it. Can you provide test scripts and desired output?

Comment: I edited my original post. Hopefully it better explains what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH myCTE AS (
SELECT node_id, clientid, datepart(weekday, timestamp) wkday
FROM YourTable
)
SELECT T1.node_id, T1.count(distinct clientid) total, 'weekdays' category
FROM myCTE T1
WHERE wkday in (2,3,4,5,6) --weekdays
UNION ALL
SELECT T1.node_id, T1.count(distinct clientid) total, 'weekends' category
FROM myCTE T1
WHERE wkday in (1,7) --weekends
SELECT T1.node_id, T1.count(distinct clientid) total, 'mon-sat' category
FROM myCTE T1
WHERE wkday in (2,3,4,5,6,7) --mon-sat
```

Hope this helps... using the script above, you can follow that if you need more groupings of different combination of days, just keep adding a union all and change the where clause criteria.